# The yellow person icon on the google map can't be moved around the maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have this problem
The yellow person icon on the google map can be moved around the maps of google api
And I want the same for my google map component.

On the Google map on the home page, if a user drags the yellow Pegmen near the edge of the map, the map must automatically respond to reveal the new map area to the Pegmen address. This function is convenient for the user to access areas outside the area of the displayed map. Google Maps does this. But my component does not, is this possible?

```
<script>
     var map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ('map'), {
       Zoom: 17,
       Center: {lat: 4.6680202, lng: -74.0622556},
     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

File a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3%20type:Enhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) with google maps v3 javascript API. The desired behaviour is not currently available (i.e. it's not just you).